# Logging the response body with Nginx Lua

Tags: nginx

I have a reverse proxy that l want to log request body with which currently looks lie

log_format my_tracking '"$request" "$http_soapaction" "$http_content_type" "$request_body"';

which is logging everything wonderfully, now I want to log the response body of these requests its turning out to be a lot harder. I have been trying to use the Lua module (which I've compiled into Nginx 1.3.14) but I can't find any examples of how to do this, I'm definitely stretching my technical ability so any assistance would be greatly received.

Thanks,
Will
Edit Reply Quote Report

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, setting variable in body_filter and then passing it into log file doesn't work. I've checked this configuration and it worked but unfortunately nginx logs data into error.log:

```
 error_log  logs/error.log  info;

 location / {
      set $myresponse;  #we must declare it first, we cannot create vars in lua
      proxy_pass http://mybackendserver;
      body_filter_by_lua 'ngx.var.myresponse = ngx.arg[1]
      ngx.log(ngx.INFO,ngx.var.myresponse)
      ';

    }
}
```

ps. Would like to know too how to log to access logs from lua module.

Comment: Hi, 
This doesn't work, it works if instead of ngx.arg[1], we put a lua string, but it won't put the body into that var.

Comment: indeed, updated post, hope this one helps.